# Invalid UUID String solr

Tags: json, indexing, solr, uuid

I am using solr to index a very large number of documents. One of my requirements is that each documents needs to have a unique id, which I tried to implement using the [Unique Key](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey) way. However, when I try using the "post" command to index the documents as normally, I get many

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">15</int></lst><lst name="error"><lst name="metadata"><str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str><str name="root-error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str></lst><str name="msg">Invalid UUID String: '/Volumes/filePlace/file1.html'</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
```

in the output, and no documents are indexed. How do I fix this?

The post command I use is regular syntax:

```
post -c NewCore .
```

where . is the current folder containing all the files.

Comment: show how you are using post command

Comment: @Persimmonium added it, but I don't think it should change anything.

Comment: I believe you need to change your id column from UUID to a string type. Would it be possible to provide the contents of the managed-schema file?

Comment: Could you include the `schema.xml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that my error was that I was indexing rich documents using the `post` tool included in solr. However, when indexing rich documents such as html with `post`, the HTTP POST request needs to have `literal.id` specified to something, otherwise it doesn't run. The `post` tool automatically sets literal.id to the file location, and since the field `id` is set to be of type UUID, this causes an error. I have now switched `id` in the managedschema file to be of type string and decided to use individual post commands such as

```
post -c NewCore -params literal.id=55 /Volumes/mainVolume/thingy.html
```

and to assign each rich document an id before it is indexed.